# How Can I know if the created GPG key is with or without the passphrase ? Let's say the key was created using gpg --gen-key without entering passphras

Tags: git, gnupg, git-secret

Git Secret
How Can I know if the created GPG key is with or without the passphrase ?

I have tried comparing the keys, one created without entering the passphrase, and the other with the passphrase, couldn't see any difference.